# How do I include og tags in a flexdashboard?

Tags: r, meta-tags, flexdashboard

I have problems making og tags work in my flexdashboard. The tags themselves should be fine and I include them in the YAML header via `scripts.html` like this:

```
---
title: "Baseball Dashboard v0.2"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: scroll
    includes:
      in_header: scripts.html
runtime: shiny
---
```

But they don't show up in the source when you go to [www.baseball-dashboard.com](https://www.baseball-dashboard.com).
They only show up when I "Inspect" the site in Chrome but not in the source. The source looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.2.0]</script>
<script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>  <script src="rmd_resources/rmd_loader.js"></script>
  <link href="rmd_resources/rmd_loader.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="__assets__/sockjs-0.3.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="__assets__/shiny-server-client.min.js"></script>
<script>preShinyInit({reconnect:true,disableProtocols:[]});</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="__assets__/shiny-server.css"/>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div data-display-if="!output.__reactivedoc__" data-ns-prefix="">
      <div id="rmd_loader_wrapper">
        <div id="rmd_loader" style="display: none">
          <p>Please wait...</p>
          <img src="rmd_resources/rmd_loader.gif"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="__reactivedoc__" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So I guess the problem is that they don't show up here.